# awscli and moving files to s3 bucket based on timestamp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a large number of files on a file system (Terabytes) and I want to move all files beyond 30 days of age to an S3 bucket.

I am pondering the most workable way of doing this and thought I might ask for some help.

I think that this command or similar may be the way to go:

```
find /home/<target> -type f -mtime +30 -print0 | tar cv | split --bytes=5120MB | gzip | s3 mv --expected-size=5368706371 - s3://bucket/<target>*.tar.gz
```

However I wonder if anyone else has already done this and may know a more appropriate way of approaching the task?